# How to solve "Update for Windows 10 Version 1511 (KB3122947) - Error 0x80070643"

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

Since several days my Windows 10 won't install the update named `KB3122947` or any other newer updates.  I always get the error `0x80070643`. What can I do to solve this issue?

---

[image]

---

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fix was to manually force the system to install the update.

#### Howto

1. Verify that Windows Update has downloaded - but not installed - the update. These are two different things. In your File Explorer, enable *Hidden items* under *View* and go to

   ```
   C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\Download\b0a5da1b24245bc4237166e09bae92da\
   ```

   Check if either `windows10.0-kb3122947-x86.cab` or `windows10.0-kb3122947-x64.cab` are present (Depending on which Windows type your have)
2. Right-click on your Start button and choose `Command Prompt (Admin)`. Paste and execute the following command corresponding to your Windows type

   <sub>**Windows x86** (32-bit)</sub>

   > dism /online /add-package /packagepath:C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\Download\b0a5da1b24245bc4237166e09bae92da\windows10.0-kb3122947-x86.cab

   <sub>**Windows x64** (64-bit)</sub>

   > dism /online /add-package /packagepath:C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\Download\c4a1b8896ce9fbfea96c1ee6890d52a5\windows10.0-kb3122947-x64.cab
3. If you see the message `The operation completed successfully.` restart your system and you're done.

   [image]

[Source](http://www.infoworld.com/article/3012221/microsoft-windows/mysterious-new-windows-10-version-1511-patch-kb-3122947-fails-to-install-with-error-0x80070643.html)

Comment: This in theory could be used on any update that fails in a similar way.  You just have to determine what the .cab file is for the update.

Comment: Could someone with a x64 Windows please confirm that the subfolder `c4a1b8896ce9fbfea96c1ee6890d52a5` is really a different one on x64 then on x86?

Comment: This solution is failing for me with the same error. Checking, I find that the kb has not downloaded.

Comment: that kb is NOT downloaded. What now?